# yet another 'You have an error in your SQL syntax'

Tags: mysql

I've counted my fields, checked my types, etc. 
This is the first of a multi-line insert.Why won't this:

```
(6972561736,'2013-02-06 04:29:17',85,'CONCORD',1000125,'First Last',92596384,'Airmia',30000166,11000.00,175697113.47,'21656:2,',,,92596384)
```

fit in

```
Table xact    
==========    
refID, date, refTypeID, ownerName1, ownerID1, ownerName2, ownerID2, argName1, argID1, amount, balance, reason, taxReceiverID, taxAmount, charID

----------

refID            int(11) PK    
date             datetime    
refTypeID        bigint(20)    
ownerName1       varchar(45)    
ownerID1         int(11)    
ownerName2       varchar(45)    
ownerID2         int(11)    
argName1         varchar(45)    
argID1           int(11)    
amount           decimal(16,4)    
balance          decimal(16,4)    
reason           varchar(64)    
taxReceiverID    int(11)    
taxAmount        decimal(16,4)    
charID           int(11)
```

Actual error:

...the right syntax to use near ',92596384),(6972540458, '2013-02-06 04:23:30',34,'Istei Poyri',3018350,'First ' at line 1

6972540458 is the start of the next record...

The full query is 8355 characters, so I hope I have given enough data.

Comment: Is `,,,` valid syntax? I've never tried.

Comment: change `'21656:2,',,,92596384)` to `'21656:2','',,'',92596384)` and I think you don't need to put `''` for decimal type.

Comment: per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html - If you are not running in strict SQL mode, any column not explicitly given a value is set to its default (explicit or implicit) value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have data for a column then add `null` (if allowed) or a default value instead of nothing like

```
,,,92596384)
 ^-----------------here
```

Comment: You confused me with your new gravatar. :)

Comment: yeah - still me. new and improved :)

Comment: The default for this field is null, and I suppose even though mysql-mode is not set, it must default to strict. this worked fine in previous versions...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full error, I would suggest replacing the `,,,` with `null` values:

```
,'21656:2,',null,null,92596384)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `NULL` or empty quotes `''` instead of nothing between your commas.

```
(6972561736,'2013-02-06 04:29:17',85,'CONCORD',1000125,'First Last',92596384,'Airmia',30000166,11000.00,175697113.47,'21656:2,',NULL,NULL,92596384)
```

Possibly because you've also got a wild comma in there after **21656:2**.

```
(6972561736,'2013-02-06 04:29:17',85,'CONCORD',1000125,'First Last',92596384,'Airmia',30000166,11000.00,175697113.47,'21656:2',NULL,NULL,NULL,92596384)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
check '21656:2' and you had added an extra column 

   (6972561736,'2013-02-06 04:29:17',85,'CONCORD',1000125,'First Last',92596384,'Airmia',30000166,11000.00,175697113.47,'21656:2',,,92596384)
```